# Testing iOS5 app on iPhone 3GS - GPS not working

Tags: iphone, ios5, gps, iphone-3gs

I'm developing an app that uses location, specifically it needs the precise location obtained from GPS.

I've got an iPhone 3GS for testing, which is running the latest version of iOS 5 (5.0.1), but it only seems to get coarse location based on WiFi (my friend's 3GS exhibits the same behaviour). This is apparently a widespread problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3395846?start=0&tstart=0

I was testing the GPS using the official maps app (which works fine on a 4S). I'm somewhat confused as to how exactly GPS is not working on 3GS phones running iOS 5.

Is there a solution/fix to make GPS work when developing iPhone apps? (As in the app i'm making, not the maps app.)

Comment: this thread may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857450/gps-app-stopped-working-on-ios-5-location-manager-not-updating